# How to use html5shiv with Iframe sandbox attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5shiv

I would like to use html5shiv for support on IE9 but I can't get it to work. I have installed this in the head section:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>

<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I need support for HTML5 Iframe sandbox:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.telegraaf.nl" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

The website in the Iframe will break out the iframe in IE9 so that means the sandbox is not working. I think the problem is maybe that the sandbox is an attribute of iframe rather than a "style method/element".

So basically I need some advice on this. What else can I do? Is there a plugin (jquery?javascript?) somewhere that will support sandbox in IE?

Comment: Actually IE9 supports HTML5.

Comment: @undefined Oke but it doesn't seem to support sandbox. (and I actually need it for IE8 as well )

Comment: The html5shiv script does not add any functionality – it simply makes unknown elements known to IE by creating them. This does not influence what _attributes_ IE might support on certain elements; and besides that, `iframe` is not even in the list of elements that the shiv deals with.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, I already kinda figured that out (Im new at this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need html5shiv in this case but a polyfill for that property.

Comment: I did everything suggested over here: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-use-the-webshims-polyfill/ It doesn't work for iframe sandbox so it seems. I did accept your answer because I don't think there is anything else...This is what I did http://jsfiddle.net/u5Kpq/2/ Doesn't work in IE9   Any other suggestions..?

Comment: In short, IE < 10 doesn't support sandbox attribute (http://caniuse.com/iframe-sandbox). Here is where it works: http://caniuse.com/iframe-sandbox It seems that a polyfill doesn't exist for this attribute.